# Html Agility Pack is truncating a meta tag's value

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using the Html Agility Pack to parse some html and am having an issue with a poorly formatted meta tag.

Given this meta tag:

```
"<meta name=\"productattributes\" value=\"shop: Baby|category: Category|category: Babies\" r\"us=\"\" exclusives|family:=\"\" strollers|name:=\"\" baby=\"\" trend=\"\" expedition=\"\" elx=\"\" travel=\"\" system=\"\" stroller=\"\" -=\"\" everglade|price:=\"\" 239.99\"=\"\">"
```

When I call:

```
HtmlNode productAttributes = hap.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//meta[@name='productattributes']");

var productAttributesStr = productAttributes.GetAttributeValue("value", "");
```

The resulting productAttributesStr is ending up with the value truncated at the \”r”:

"shop: Baby|category: Category|category: Babies"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `"` as data inside an attribute value delimited with the same character. The first one you hits ends the attribute value. You need to represent them using entities: `&quot;`

Comment: It's not my html so I need to figure out a workaround to parse it. The html is coming from toysrus.com.

Comment: You'll have to write a custom fixup routine to correct the errors before you try to parse it then. (Or get the supplier to fix it at the source).

Answer (score 0):

The html is in fact invalid. The string you copied (without C# \" added) is:

```
<meta name="productattributes" value="shop: Baby|category: Category|category: Babies" r"us="" exclusives|f...
```

So the attribute 'value' finishes at Baby, there is a " (double quote) after the r, etc...

Comment: It's not my html so I need to figure out a workaround to parse it. The html is coming from toysrus.com.